# Extract text and evaluate in bash

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I need some help getting a script up and running. Basically I have some data that comes from a command output and want to select some of it and evaluate

Example data is

```
JSnow <jsnow@email.com> John Snow spotted 30/1/2015
BBaggins <bbaggins@email.com> Bilbo Baggins spotted 20/03/2015
Batman <batman@email.com> Batman spotted 09/09/2015
```

So far I have something along the lines of

```
# Define date to check
check=$(date -d "-90 days" "+%Y/%m/%d")

# Return user name 
for user in $(command | awk '{print $1}')
    do 
    # Return last logon date
    $lastdate=(command | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==spotted) $(i+1)}')
    # Evaluation date again current -90days
        if $lastdate < $check; then
            printf "$user not logged on for ages"
        fi
    done
```

I have a couple of problems, not least the fact that whilst I can get information from places I don't know how to go about getting it all together!! I'm also guessing my date evaluation will be more complicated but at this point that's another problem and just there to give a better idea of my intentions. If anyone can explain the logical steps needed to achieve my goal as well as propose a solution that would be great. Thanks

Comment: `$lastdate=` should be `lastdate=`. `if $lastdate < $check` should be `if [[ "$lastdate" -lt "$check" ]]`. May I recommend http://www.shellcheck.net?

Comment: Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach (see, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). The general purpose text manipulation tool that comes on every UNIX installation is awk. This uses GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { check = systime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60) }
{
    user = $1
    date = gensub(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,"\\3 \\2 \\1 0 0 0",1,$NF)
    secs = mktime(date)

    if (secs < check) {
        printf "%s not logged in for ages\n", user
    }
}

$ cat file
JSnow <jsnow@email.com> John Snow spotted 30/1/2015
BBaggins <bbaggins@email.com> Bilbo Baggins spotted 20/03/2015
Batman <batman@email.com> Batman spotted 09/09/2015

$ cat file | awk -f tst.awk
JSnow not logged in for ages
BBaggins not logged in for ages
Batman not logged in for ages
```

Replace `cat file` with `command`.

Comment: Hi, this was a massive help. I do believe the gensub has wrong format for the mktime though and needed to be \\1 \\2 \\3 as it seems to expect time year first. Either way I've got what I need working now and realise that gawk is way more powerful that I thought. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, my sample data was indeed listed like that. Thanks again for your help